# Coverflow in HTML5 for iPhone/iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, html, webkit, ipod-touch, coverflow

I have to do a web page destined for iPhone and iPod-touch that needs to incorporate the Coverflow style of apple in a page to display a list of videos.

I've heard something about gizmos that could help, but I can't find anything relevant or that could work properly with the iPhone/iPod-Touch navigation.

Anyone knows something that could help me getting started?

Thanks
-Stephanie

Answer (score 6):

Try ContentFlow:
http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Here is an example that is working on my iPhone :
http://www.majes.fr/

Answer (score 2):

This is the best one which i found till now ;) [Coverflow](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/#more-1785)

Answer (score 2):

**This is a cross-browser implementation of Cover Flow: http://luwes.co/labs/js-cover-flow/**

The primary mode works in HTML5 (JavaScript/CSS) and it has a fallback for older browsers in flash. It supports mobile, you can flip through the covers with a simple swipe gesture.

Tested on: Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE8+, iPad, iPhone

Comment: It's a nice implementation, however the biggest drawback is that it does not degrade gracefully (disable JavaScript and boom, no content) and is absolutely not accessible to disabled people. Because it relies on external JSON source, it is also unusable in CMS-generated galleries like Wordpress. Instead of parsing a JSON file, it would have been better to style figure elements in the html.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not following the external JSON comment though, are you saying that it's impossible to have a JSON file in a Wordpress site? Nonetheless the script also allows inline JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: http://paulbakaus.com/2008/05/31/coverflow-anyone/

Though it doesn't seem that there is any official way to do it because CSS transforms only all a 2d matrix, so you can't get a trapezium shape.

Answer (score 1):

you can find tons of coverflow samples in google
but all the samples that i found are too complex(a lot of files or hard to implement) and they don't give what i was looking
so i decide to create a coverflow

1.-  less files

2.-  easy to implement

3.- Works with Webkit (Safari, Safari Mobile and Chrome)

the code that i'm going to show is just to give you a clue
of what can you do with your project

this is a very simple sample that only shows you the essential
it's not a final work

this coverflow works with a input range (slider)
and thats it

When you get the idea of how coverflow works
you will be able to add more features clicks, touches, flip cover....

Finally here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>CoverFlow</title>
<style>
  html { height: 100%; }
  body { background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(gray 0%, black 100%); }

  #coverflow { 
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 100px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 500;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }


  #container { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;     
  margin-left: 350px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  }

  .holder {
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 100px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
     -webkit-box-reflect: below 4px
     -webkit-gradient(
     linear,
     left top,
     left bottom,
     color-stop(0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
     color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)),
     color-stop(1, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3))
     );
  }

  .slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 430px;
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #999;
  opacity: .5;
  }

 .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 width: 50px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #999), color-stop(.5, #000) );
 }

 #log { color: white; font-size: 30pt; }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body onload="flow()">

 <div id="coverflow">
 <div id="container">
      <div class="holder" id="1"><img src="../img/1.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="2"><img src="../img/2.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="3"><img src="../img/3.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="4"><img src="../img/4.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="5"><img src="../img/5.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="6"><img src="../img/6.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="7"><img src="../img/7.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="8"><img src="../img/8.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="9"><img src="../img/9.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="10"><img src="../img/1.jpg" width="200"></div>
      <div class="holder" id="11"><img src="../img/2.jpg" width="200"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <input id="slider" class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="11" value="6" onchange="flow();">
 <a id="log">value</a>
 <script>
 function flow() { 

 var space = 2;
 var coverCount = 11;
 var current = slider.value;
 var cover = document.getElementById(current + "");
 var position = [0, 230, 180, 130, 80, 30, -20, -70, -120, -170, -220, -270]; 

 for (var i = current; i < (coverCount +1); i++)     
  { 
 document.getElementById(i + "").style.webkitTransform = "translate3d("+((i+space)*50)+"px,0,-10px) rotateY(-65deg)";
 document.getElementById(i + "").style.zIndex = -i + "";
  }

 for (var i = 1; i < current; i++)     
  { 
 document.getElementById(i + "").style.webkitTransform = "translate3d("+((i-space)*50)+"px,0,-10px) rotateY(65deg)";
 document.getElementById(i + "").style.zIndex = i + "";
  }

  cover.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d("+(slider.value*50)+"px,0,100px) rotateY(0deg)"; 
  cover.style.zIndex = current + "";     
  document.getElementById("container").style.marginLeft =  position[current] + "px"; 
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = slider.value + "";
  }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

i know you can find a lot of better coverflows this is just to share

Just remember to replace the path of the images and/or names

Hope it helps

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I mainly stick with native App development, so I don't know if there is an existing cover flow implementation, but using [Dashcode Parts](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/PartsReference/PartsReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH14-SW5) you can add some more complex UI elements.

Comment: Yes, I see dashcode can help adding more complex elements easily, but unfortunately nothing seems to point to something even close to coverflow. I'll have a deeper look, maybe I can find something that will please my DA anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try xFlow! http://xflow.pwhitrow.com

Answer (score 0):

i just made this
http://coulisse.luvdasun.com/

not sure if it works on iphone / ipod, i still have to test that

gr.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I have developed specifically for iOS devices. Has touch gestures enabled.
http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/css3-coverflow-animation-for-ios-adding-touch-gestures/

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.